# Make encryption key more secure?

Tags: java, encryption

I'm looking for a way to secure the encryption key which i use to encrypt and decrypt data.

I do encrypt/decrypt on a separate server (my crypt server), this way my encryption key is not on my live server.

When my live server issues a encryption/decryption task to the crypt server, he also supplies a salt (saved on the live server). This way i use salt + encryption key for my encryption needs.

The live server can also send other information like id's (userid, item id and such) along the salt to the crypt server. Is it more secure if i append one or more of these id's to the encryption key?

Like:

```
final sEnckey="mykey"
enckey=sEnckey+_+userid+_+itemid
encrypt(enckey, salt)
```

The thinking behind this is that if hacker get hold of enckey he still can't decode, cause he needs salt + all the id's.

Are there more tricks like this?

Comment: what if the salt is leaked? also you can check if you can use public key encryption.Here you can use two key pairs (if both server need to encrypt and decrypt).

Comment: @redflar3 if salt is leaked (ie someone hacked the liver server) a hacker still needs access to crypt server for base encryption key, in addition all the id's used in the combined encryption key. Or am i overlooking something?

Comment: can you clarify which server encrypts, which one decrypts, how has key and how has salt..

Comment: The crypt server encrypts/decrypts hence the name ;-)

Comment: Please read this: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18197/why-shouldnt-we-roll-our-own, before you invest more time into your own security schema. Doing security and cryptography right is hard (really hard) and takes a great deal of expertise, which, based on your question you do not possess yet (no offence meant here), so if you are seriously concerned with the possible attacks, you better use some existing security service/protocol instead.

Comment: @zeppelin cheers, an interesting read there. But i'm not sure what you mean with "existing security service/protocol", can you give a practical example or product or are these more standards you need implement like server/client authentication with client/sever ssl certificates?

Comment: @TinusTate Hi. Well, it depends on the task you are trying to solve, you post concentrates on the technical details, but could you elaborate a bit on your use cases.

Comment: @zeppelin currently i'm looking for ways to make the encryption more secure even when one or more servers are compromised. I do this by placing elements that are needed for encryption on different servers. Or by using different information from different servers/data sources to construct the encryption key. This seems quite specialized for a newbie like me, I'm wondering if there are existing protocols or services for such things.

Comment: At very least, when you move the encryption functionality to a separate service, accessible over the network connection, you are creating a new "attack surface", which can (possibly) be exploited, unless you take some special measures to prevent it (establish a mutual authentication and a secure data channel between them).

E.g. someone might break into a workstation in your network and use this as a base to eavesdrop the communications or send fake requests to your encryption service on behalf of other users, e.t.c.

Comment: Also if someone compromises your live server, he does not really need to know the encryption key, to decrypt the information he wants,  as he can just ask your crypt server to do it for him instead (on behalf of your  live server which is under his control now).

Anyway, I think the best you can do, is provide as many details on your use cases and encryption algorithms, as possible, and re-post this question to a specialized security community: 
http://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @zeppelin a secure data channel with client/server certificates is indeed in place. There are indeed ways, not easy though, to simulate the client on live server. Going to read a bit about how game servers detect changed clients or maybe something like that can be prevented with code signing, interesting! Heading over to security.stackexchange.com to do even more reading. Thanks zeppelin!